# Integrate a built-in Update function in shell in order to receive OTA updates when there are available

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i'm struggled here with this thing that it would be awesome if it's gonna be integrated.
Well my idea is to, create a function which it will be runned at a certain time which is gonna to check if there is a new version of the script . But i don't know how to put the commands together.
I already have a sort of sketch Here:

```
SCRIPT_NAME="$0"
ARGS="$@"
NEW_FILE="/tmp/blog.sh"
VERSION="1.0"

check_upgrade () {

# check if there is a new version of this file
# here, hypothetically we check if a file exists in the disk.
# it could be an apt/yum check or whatever...
[ -f "$NEW_FILE" ] && {


# install a new version of this file or package
# again, in this example, this is done by just copying the new file
echo "Found a new version of me, updating myself..."
cp "$NEW_FILE" "$SCRIPT_NAME"
rm -f "$NEW_FILE"

# note that at this point this file was overwritten in the disk
# now run this very own file, in its new version!
echo "Running the new version..."
$SCRIPT_NAME $ARGS

# now exit this old instance
exit 0
}
```

I know it's possible to do this, but i didn't found anything useful on internet.
Every advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: what did you get from running that script? also why dont you just compare version numbers? unless thats the version of the update script at the top.

Comment: That's why i want to do but if the file needs to be downloaded and it is online ?

Comment: do you have a yum or apt repo set up?

Comment: None of them i was thinking to use curl but i don't know how to compare the current local version with the one online

Comment: I don't want to create an apt repo just for a script which can be easily downloaded

Comment: why not use wget and download the file, then comapre the version number and if they are the same just delete the downloaded file?

Comment: Well yeah, you right and the process can be easily hidden, by displaying only in the case if the update is available

Comment: I think tha it can't be integrated generically, because each script is different and can't stop anytime. You need to indicate the moments where the script can stop and check updates (and install and launch it). Furthermore, you script don't kill the older script after run the new script. It's not really important, but you could have after a time, many bash process.I propose you to create a master script (that you can't automatically update) with a master loop that run a slave script that you could update.You can for a best efficiency, try to use GnuParrallel  but I don't know, if you can here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the script is always running, make another script that curls the file and checks it against the original. Something like:

```
if [ version newer ]; then
    kill old verseion
    mv "new version" 'old version"
    ./new version
else:
    delete tmp file
fi
```

Run it with cron at intervals you see fit